# Beginner problems with perl

Tags: arrays, perl, variables, hash

I have been tasked with correcting bugs in a chunk of Perl code and had a few questions about it (as I am new to Perl).

My first issue is what does the exclamation mark do?

```
if (!$superceded{returned->{$field}}) {
          $found = 0;
          foreach (blahblahblah)
```

My second problem is what does it mean if you have a variable $supercede and a hash %superceded and you write

```
  (keys %$superceded)
```

Finally I have read up on these next two but I am still unsure on how they work. Setting a variable equal to shift and how to use "last;".

Thanks for any help and advice.

Answer (score 2):

`!` is logical negation, which means if `$cond` is true, `!$cond` will be false. You could learn more about [Truth and Falsehood](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood) from [`perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html).

If `$hashref` is a hash reference, then `%$hashref` is the hash that that reference referred to. For example,

```
my %hash = ( key1 => "val1", key2 => "val2" );
my $hashref = \%hash; # create a hash reference
while (my ($key, $val) = each %$hashref) {
    # do something
}
```

Oh, you also could write something like this

```
my $hash = \%hash;
```

A little confusion to human readers, but Perl will accept it without any problem. To Perl, `$hash` and `%hash` are two completely different variables, and could be totally unrelated.

You could learn more about reference from [`perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). And `@$arrayref` is similar, except in this case `$arrayref` is an array reference, it could be created by `$arrayref = \@array;`.

> Setting a variable equal to shift

Do you mean something like this:

```
my $val = shift;
```

In this case, this means `my $val = shift @_;`, which will remove the first element of `@_` and assign it to `$val`. See `perldoc -f shift` for further details.

> how to use "last;"

If you want to finish a loop early, you could use `last`. For example,

```
foreach my $i (1..100) {
    print "$i\n";
}
```

will print 1 to 100, and this

```
foreach my $i (1..100) {
    print "$i\n";
    last if $i == 5;
}
```

will only print 1 to 5. See [`perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Loop-Control) for further details.

Comment: Thank you so much but I have two final questions. If I had the hash %superceded and the variable $supercede would my reference be %$supercede or %$superceded? And the code doesn't define any references, do you think that is part of the errors I need to fix or does it mean something else? Again thanks a lot for the great answer.

Comment: @DanielStewart That depends. If `$supercoded` is a hash reference, then `%$supercoded` is correct; if you only have `%supercoded` but on `$supercoded` or `$supercoded` is not a hash reference, then `%$supercoded` is wrong. `$supercoded` and `%supercoded` could be two completely different and unrelated variables.

Comment: @DanielStewart: Note also that the spelling is *superseded*. I know it's not a spelling test, but correct English does give a better impression

Comment: @Borodin Actually, "supercede" is a variant spelling of "supersede."

Comment: @LeeDuhem: It's strictly incorrect as it comes from Latin *sedere*, to sit, whereas words like precede and accede come from *cederer*, to go or to yield. But it may be accepted as being a de facto alternative spelling because it is such a common mistake.

Comment: @DanielStewart: If it's spelled that way in the code you've been given then you should stick to that. Correcting the spelling of a potential employer is a worse move than getting your own spelling wrong!

Comment: @Borodin Yes, you are right. "supersede" should be the correct spelling.